# Tendermint consensus: Are validators "known" and "pre-selected"?

Tags: consensus, proof-of-stake, validation

What are similarities and differences between **Tendermint** consensus and **Proof-of-Stak**?

For example, in both consensus, a validator is selected randomly (I think in Tendermint consensus they are selected in a round robin process).

And I think in Tendermint consensus, validators are **known** and **pre-selected**, unlike Proof-of-Stake consensus. Is it true? and if yes, **what entity** does confirm a known validator?

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are known. They are selected via a round-robin fashion. The Tendermint team intend to add a VRF to randomly select validators:

https://github.com/tendermint/tendermint/issues/763

Comment: Thank you. So, do it mean that there is a finite set of "pre-selected" validators (permissioned)? OR everyboby is permitted to join set of validators (permission-less)?  Thanks